# Monthly reminder Web service

Tags: asp.net

I had written one web service which fires on every miniutes...
I want to fire a mail to my manager in every month on say xyz date....
this task shld repeted on every month on same date...
So can any one tell me how to do this..?
I mean to say the block of code which i will write shld get executed on same date of every month...

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to schedule jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I use [VisualCron](http://www.visualcron.com) for scheduling web and WCF services. The advantage is that you just paste the URL in the tool. Then VisualCron will discover all methods and their parameters. The actual parameters can be hard coded or you can use dynamic values, for instance, create a date in a specific format.

The output from the Task will be returned and can be used in other Tasks for further processing.